# Testing the validity of many gzipped files on a Windows system using Perl

Tags: windows, perl, gzip

I have thousands (or more) of gzipped files in a directory (on a Windows system) and one of my tools consumes those gzipped files. If it encounters a corrupt gzip file, it conveniently ignores them instead of raising an alarm.

I have been trying to write a Perl program that loops through each file and makes a list of files which are corrupt.

I am using the [`Compress::Zlib`](https://metacpan.org/module/Compress::Zlib) module, and have tried reading the first 1KB of each file, but that did not work since some of the files are corrupted towards the end (verified during the manual extract, alarm raised only towards the end) and reading first 1KB doesn't show a problem. I am wondering if a CRC check of these files will be of any help.

Questions:

1. Will CRC validation work in this case? If yes, how does it work? Will the true CRC be part of the gzip header, and we are to compare it with the calculated CRC from the file we have? How do I accomplish this in Perl?
2. Are there any other simpler ways to do this?

Comment: Thanks, but this is a windows system, I don't think gzip is natively built into this, right? I want to see if there are better opportunities since having extra utilities installed into by server could be pain

Comment: You should try to figure out why you have corrupt gzip files in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the only way to check a gzip file is to decompress it until you get an error, or get to the end successfully.  You do not however need to store the result of the decompression.

The CRC stored at the end of a gzip file is the CRC of the uncompressed data, not the compressed data.  To use it for verification, you have to decompress all of the data.  This is what `gzip -t` does, decompressing the data and checking the CRC, but not storing the uncompressed data.

Often a corruption in the compressed data will be detected before getting to the end.  But if not, then the CRC, as well as a check against an uncompressed length also stored at the end, will with a probability very close to one detect a corrupted file.

Comment: I had to resort to gzip -t, using GNUWin32, and using a system command within perl

Answer (score 0):

The [*`Archive::Zip` FAQ*](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Archive-Zip/lib/Archive/Zip/FAQ.pod#How_to_test_file_integrity?) gives some very good guidance on this.

It looks like the best option for you is to check the CRC of each member of the archives, and a sample program that does this -- [`ziptest.pl`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.41/examples/ziptest.pl) -- comes with the [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Zip) module installation.

Comment: Archive Zip does not handle gzip files is what I saw in FAQ section

Answer (score -1):

It should be easy to test the file is not corrupt by just using "gunzip -t" command, gunzip is available for windows as well and should come with gzip package.